# After upgrading to Windows 8.1, unable to run Windows Phone emulator without memory error

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

After I updated my Samsung Series 9 SSD laptop with 8GB of RAM to Windows 8.1, (not even a year old, and top-of-line when purchased last november), I am now unable to run the Windows Phone emulator while debugging my WP8 app.

The error messages I see is:

> "Not enough memory in the system to start the virtual machine emulator
>   WVGA 512MB.user with ram size 512 megabytes"

Well, the instant I attempt to run a build, it the machine immediately goes from 25% memory consumed to 80% consumed. Even after I close Visual Studio Express 2012, still it is stuck at 80% memory consumption according to the task manager. At this point, I am unable to run the Windows Phone emulator to test my app.

How can I work around this issue without replacing my hardware?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS Express? Since yesterday VS2013 Express is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-express). I know it's a long shot but maybe worth a try..

Comment: Do you have the Visual Studio Update 3 installed? That addresses compatibility issues with VS2012 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: VS Express 2013 doesn't include support for Windows Phone.

Comment: After installing VS Update 3, VS Express 2012 will not launch at all. I am now totally unable to do any Windows Phone development at all.

Comment: OK, after a complete reinstall of Windows 8, upgrade to 8.1, install of VS Express, and installation of the update 3, it is working again now and not giving me memory errors.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my Surface Pro and Visual Studio 2012 and 2013. Only way to get the Emulator working is to start the VM in the first minute after a reboot.

Comment: Good to you, if I install the WP SDK on my W8.1 machine, blue screens problems arise. It seems the HyperV drivers are very conflicting with my Network Adapter drivrs... GG Microsoft...

Comment: You better to buy this: http://r.ebay.com/ojn55V and upgrade to 8GB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft has now posted [a KB article with information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911380) about how to edit the registry to correct this:

1. Start Registry Editor.
2. Locate the following registry subkey:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization
3. Right-click the Virtualization
   folder, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
4. Type MemoryReserve, and then press Enter.
5. Double-click MemoryReserve,
   enter 2048 in the Value data box, select the Decimal option, and
   then click OK.
6. Close Registry Editor.

Comment: i followed this, Still can't get it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post comments yet but I wanted to confirm being able to start the emulator after starting the Hyper-V Manager. I was getting memory errors trying to launch the emulator; I started the emulator via the Hyper-V Manager and was able to launch it from VS2013.

Comment: Yes I have to do this every time now too.

Answer (score 0):

Closing down some applications (eg SQL Server) did the trick for me.