# "Not enough memory..." error when attempting to start windows phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I actually got this error (image below) sometimes (not always), which means my hardware is fine (?).

[image]

Everytime I got this error I tried a walk around by starting the VM inside HyperV Manager ([After upgrading to Windows 8.1, unable to run Windows Phone emulator without memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739016/after-upgrading-to-windows-8-1-unable-to-run-windows-phone-emulator-without-mem)).

But now, even when I started it, it still didn't work (image below).

[image]

The errors occurred when I started using Application Deployment to test a xap file in WVGA (not WVGA 512 MB) emulator, the emulator didn't start and after that whatever version of Emulator I tried, the same error appeared.

I tried deleting all the VMs in VM Manager and then started VS and run the emulator again but it still didn't work. I also restarted windows but the problem remained unsolved.  I'm using VS2012 and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary reason behind this is that your machine doesn't have enough available memory for the VM to launch.

Here is a [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911380/en-us) that was recently posted to get around this by setting a registry key that limits the amount of memory available to the host machine.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911380/en-us

I have used the above fix and it worked for me.

Comment: Updating this thread -- Hyper-V changed memory management techniques in Windows 10 build 15002 and later.

See the memory management section here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/01/10/cool-new-things-for-hyper-v-on-desktop/

Answer (score 1):

This message is telling you that you have insufficient memory on your PC to start this virtual machine.

Try closing down other applications (such as Visual Studio, any Office apps etc), then starting the emulator in Hyper-V manager. Then you can restart Visual Studio etc.

I've noticed this seems to happen to me more often under Windows 8.1 than I remember happening under Windows 8 on a 4GB RAM laptop.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be occurring significantly more often since 8.1 and VS2013 than it ever did on 8 and VS2012.

My work around (as RAM is soldered to my board so no upgrade path) is to reboot, load VS2013 immediately, start the app in the emulator I need and make sure I leave it open.